# Help Deriving the Midpoint Formula

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

One of the problems in one of the packets that I'm going through to review for a pre-test for an independent-study calculus class has asked me to derive the [midpoint formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint#Formulas).  I've gotten to the point where I have the following equation:

$$2 x_2 x_m  -  2 x_m x_1  +  2 y_2 y_m  -  2 y_m y_1  = x_2^2 - x_1^2 + y_2^2 - y_1^2$$

Would it be mathematically correct to split this into the following two equations…:

$$
\begin{cases}
2 x_2 x_m  -  2 x_m x_1 = x_2^2 - x_1^2 \\
2 y_2 y_2  -  2 y_m y_1 = y_2^2 - y_1^2
\end{cases}
$$

…and treat them as a system of equations?  If so, then how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not split this equation.
That would be the same as saying
$a+b=c+d$
can be split into
$a=c$ and $b=d$.

If the points are
$P_1, P_2, $ and $P_m$,
for $P_m$ to be the midpoint
between
$P_1$ and $P_2$,
then
one way of writing this is that
$P_m$ must be on the line
between $P_1$ and$P_2$
(i.e.,
$P_m
=tP_1+(1-t)P_2
$
for
$0 \le t \le 1$)
and
$P_m$ must be at the halfway position
(i.e., $t = \frac12$).

Another way is that
$|P_1-P_m| = |P_2-P_m|$
and
$|P_1-P_m| = |P_2-P_1|/2$
.
This way gives you two equations 
for the two unknowns
of the x and y components
of $P_m$.

Comment: Ah, of course!  I'm a nincompoop for not realizing I would need a second equation when I started doing my derivation from the first of the two equations you listed in your second derivation method!

Comment: Glad to be of service.